# Is anything wrong with this proof idea for showing that evaluation in the simply-typed lambda calculus always halts?

Tags: lambda-calculus, type-theory

Consider the simply-typed lambda calculus over some set of base types, with call-by-value evaluation semantics. (Exactly what is discussed in *Types and Programming Languages*, in case it matters -- I'm not sure whether other books define it differently). We want to show that evaluation of any well-typed term halts after finitely many steps.

I have an idea for a proof which I find much easier to understand than the standard "logical relations" one, and I am wondering if it's correct. I'm a bit doubtful because if it is correct, why can't I find it online or in textbooks?

Let $t: T$ be a well-typed term, and consider the collection of sizes of types of arguments of lambda expressions appearing *anywhere* in $t$. The notion of "size" can be whatever you like, as long as $T\to S$ has greater size than either $T$ or $S$, and sizes are nonnegative integers. For concreteness, let's use "number of arrows in the type's written representation".

For example, if $A$ is a base type, $a_0:A$ some constant, and $$t = \left(\lambda f:(A\to A)\to A.\lambda g:A\to A. f\,g\right)(\lambda h:A\to A. a_0)(\lambda a:A.a_0)$$

then the sizes of interest to us are 2, 1, 1, and 0.

We show that if $t\to t'$, where $t$ is well-typed, then some lambda abstraction whose argument's type is of size $k$ will disappear and be replaced with zero or more lambda abstractions whose arguments' types are of sizes strictly less than $k$.

The result then follows from the obvious fact that the operation of repeatedly removing some element $k$ from a finite list of non-negative integers and then adding zero or more non-negative integers smaller than $k$ cannot be performed infinitely many times. (If anyone is not convinced of this, I can prove it in the comments).

We proceed by induction on the structure of $t$. If $t$ is a value, then $t\not \to t'$, contradicting our assumption. If $t = s_1 s_2$ where neither $s_1$ nor $s_2$ is a value, then for some $s_1'$ with $s_1 \to s_1'$, $t' = s_1' s_2$, and the claim is true by induction. Similarly if $t = v s$ for a value $v$ and non-value $s$.

The last remaining case is $t = v_1 v_2$ where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are values. Then there must be some types $T_1$ and $T_2$ such that $v_2: T_2$ and $v_1: T_2\to T_1$. Then $v_1$ must have the form $\lambda x:T_2.s_1$ for some term $s$.

If $T_2$ is a base type, clearly substituting $x$ by $v_2$ in $v_1$ cannot violate our condition, since it destroys $v_1$ without creating *any* new lambda abstractions. Otherwise, $T_2$ must have the form $S_1\to S_2$, and $v_2$ the form $\lambda y:S_1.s_2$. Then substituting $v_2$ into $v_1$ might create many new copies of $v_2$, i.e., lambda expressions whose arguments have type $S_1$. But it gets rid of $v_1$, a lambda expression whose type is $T_2=S_1\to S_2$, which is larger than $S_1$, and again our condition is preserved.

Comment: Related but not duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319149/what-breaks-the-turing-completeness-of-simply-typed-lambda-calculus

Comment: You should make the theorem statement that you are proving explicit. For example, you talk about contradicting an assumption. What assumption? Are you considering only closed terms? If so, you should say so. If not, then it is not true that values of function types need to be of the form of lambda abstractions. You should define the metric and orderings explicitly since your metric seems to produce sequence(/tree?) of numbers, not a single number. You also seem to be implicitly using the fact that $\beta$-reduction preserves typeability. Being more explicit will help you evaluate your proof.

Comment: This is in essence the invariant encoded by the logical relation defined by induction on types.

Comment: @DerekElkins Sorry, I know the proof is not written in a very clear way. I think the ideas made more sense in my head than they do on paper... I can try to edit it tomorrow.